# st_as_sf() gives integers instead of geometries

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to convert a datatable with lat/long coordinates to a SF object.

In other repos, and indeed in my own past work, this functions properly:

```
points_sf <- st_as_sf(x = data, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326, remove = FALSE)
```

However, my result looks like this:

| site | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 12 |

I am getting simple integers rather than the expected format of an SF geometry, e.g. `POINT(-79.79580 34.24330)`. I've verified that latitude and longitude are both numeric before running this line.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: make and test a small, reproducible example, e.g `data.frame(x = 1, y = 1) |> sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"))`. If this works, compare it to your own data and see what's different.